# Efficient calculation of all permutations mapping a vector into another in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, permutation, combinatorics, enumeration

Given two vectors, I would like to calculate (in Python) all permutations (as vectors of coordinates) which map the first vector into the second. The vectors are given as `numpy` arrays of the same length, I call them `f_arr` (the source vector mapping from) and `t_arr` (the target vector mapping too). So I am looking for permutations `perm` of the index vector `list(range(len(f_arr)))` for which `f_arr[perm]` becomes equal to `t_arr`. It is important that the vectors can have repeated elements.

It is also important that I do not want to generate all the permutations. For example, the answers in this post do not work for me:
[How do I generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-do-i-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

I have the following inefficient code. What I am looking for is an efficient backtracking algorithm, preferably implemented in an optimized Python library, which can use something like the `positions` vector below and generate **only** the valid permutations which **map** `f_arr` to `t_arr`.

```
f_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,4], dtype=np.uint8)  # vector mapping from
t_arr = np.array([3,1,4,3,4,2], dtype=np.uint8)  # vector mapping to

positions = [np.where(f_arr == a)[0] for a in t_arr]
for perm in itertools.product(*positions):
    if len(perm) == len(set(perm)):
        print(f'{perm} -> {f_arr[list(perm)]}')
    else:  # this branch is only for demonstration
        print(f'Not a permutation: {perm}')
```

which prints:

```
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1)
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1)
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1)
(2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1) -> [3 1 4 3 4 2]
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1)
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 5, 2, 5, 1)
(2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1) -> [3 1 4 3 4 2]
Not a permutation: (2, 0, 5, 4, 5, 1)
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1)
(4, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1) -> [3 1 4 3 4 2]
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1)
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1)
(4, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1) -> [3 1 4 3 4 2]
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 5, 2, 5, 1)
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1)
Not a permutation: (4, 0, 5, 4, 5, 1)
```

Is there some Python library which can efficiently generate **only** the valid permutations which **map** `f_arr` to `t_arr`?

Comment: I'm not OP, but I don't understand how the marked duplicate answers the question. Maybe the idea is that there is no better solution than generating all permutations of indexes [which the duplicate shows how to do], and then checking by brute force whether `f_arr[indexes]` is equal to `t_arr`, but if so it would be good to explicitly state and justify that.

Comment: Yeah, neither am I, the linked answer is what I want to avoid. In fact, generating all permutations and filtering would be even worse than what I showed. Let me try to reopen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
from itertools import permutations, product
import numpy as np

def map_vec(vec1, vec2):
    i1 = vec1.argsort()
    i2 = vec2.argsort()
    i3 = i1[i2[i1].argsort()]
    _, b = np.unique(vec2[i2], return_index = True)
    c = [permutations(i) for i in np.split(i1, b)]
    return np.array([np.r_[i] for i in product(*c)], int)[:,i3]

map_vec(f_arr, t_arr)
array([[2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1],
       [2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1],
       [4, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1],
       [4, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1]])
```

---

Here is a pythonic explanation on what the code is doing:

```
from itertools import permutations, product
import numpy as np

f_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,4], dtype=np.uint8)  # vector mapping from
t_arr = np.array([3,1,4,3,4,2], dtype=np.uint8)  # vector mapping to

i1 = f_arr.argsort() # the ordered positions of first array
i2 = t_arr.argsort()[i1].argsort() # the index of the second array in first array
print(i2)
# [2 0 3 4 5 1]
```

The first value (3) in the second array is in position 2 of the first array, the second value (1) is in position 0 of the first array etc.

```
out = {} # dict holding indices for unique elements in f_arr
for i, j in enumerate(f_arr):
    out[j] = out.get(j, []) + [i] 
    
for i, j in out.items():
    if len(j) > 1:
        out[i] = list(permutations(j)) # coerced to list to visualize. No need to do so.

print(out)
# {1: [0], 2: [1], 3: [(2, 4), (4, 2)], 4: [(3, 5), (5, 3)]}

a = np.c_[[np.r_[i] for i in product(*out.values())]]
print(a)
array([[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5], # the indices for sorted f_arr: 1,2,3,3,4,4
       [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3],
       [0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
       [0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3]])


a[:, i1[i2]] # ordering back. indices for 3,1,4,3,4,2
array([[2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1],
      [2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1],
      [4, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1],
      [4, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1]])
```

Comment: It gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?` in line 10 around `np.r_[*i]`, which is very strange as I do not see any syntax errors. I have Python 3.9.6 with numpy 1.26.3, and `np.r_[]` is definitely new to me.

Comment: Replacing `np.r_[*i]` by `np.concatenate(i)` gives me the shown result. Thanks, now I just have to try to understand what your code does... :)

Comment: @gabalz i have edited the code to include explanations

Comment: Thanks a lot @Onyambu, the explanation is very clear and I learned a lot from it. There is just a small typo in the original version, `np.r_[*i]` should be `np.r_[i]` without the star in the `return` line. Please fix that and I accept the answer...

Comment: @gabalz fixed. Try it again